# create queue quorum rabbitmq in golan by streadway module

Tags: go, rabbitmq, quorum

I want to create queue **Quorum** in **Rabbitmq** with **GO**
and I wrote this code:

```
deliveries, err := c.channel.Consume(
    queue.Name, // name
    c.tag,      // consumerTag,
    false,      // noAck
    false,      // exclusive
    false,      // noLocal
    false,      // noWait
    amqp.Table{
        "x-queue-type": "quorum",
    }, // arguments )
```

but queue made of type **classic** not **quorum**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [QueueDeclare](https://github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go/blob/5039e19404bbe510a5a0bfde8268055ab5230259/channel.go#L737-L789) function to declare a queue with arguments before you consume from it.

```
args := Table{"x-queue-type": "quorum"}
channel.QueueDeclare(queue.Name,
    true,   // durable
    false,  // autoDelete
    false,  // exclusive
    false,  // wait for response
    args    // queue arguments
)
```